# Unique constraint including field in referenced table

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible to add a uniqueness constraint to a table that would include a field from a referenced table? If so, how can that be done?

(Note that I'm using *Microsoft SQL Server*.)

To explain why this is necessary, here's a simplified version of my problem.

Firstly, let's say I have a table of *things*, defining the fixed properties of each individual *thing*:

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.things(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [things$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    thing_name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [things$thing_name] UNIQUE,
    -- etc.
);
```

I also have different configurations, for a range of different elements, not just *things*, and these are captured in a table too:

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.configurations(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [configurations$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    config_name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [configurations$config_name] UNIQUE,
    -- etc.
);
```

I then want to have different configurations for each *thing*:

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.thing_configurations(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [thing_configurations$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    thing_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [thing_configurations$things_fk] REFERENCES dbo.things(id),
    quantity INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [thing_configurations$quantity] CHECK(quantity >= 0),
    -- etc.
);
```

Next, I want to identify the configuration of each thing for each particular configuration in an association table. I can ensure that the configuration and associated thing configuration are unique, but I want to ensure that each thing has no more than one thing configuration for each configuration.

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.config_thing_configurations(
    config_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [config_thing_configurations$configurations_fk] REFERENCES dbo.configurations(id),
    thing_config_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [config_thing_configurations$thing_configurations_fk] REFERENCES dbo.thing_configurations(id)
    -- How can I ensure that I do not have multiple configurations of a each thing in a configuration.
);
```

More specifically, say I have these things:

| id | thing_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Bicycle |
| ... | ... |

And these configurations:

| id | config_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Base configuration. |
| 2 | Experiment #1 |
| ... | ... |

And these thing configurations:

| id | thing_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (Apple) | 20 |
| 2 | 1 (Apple) | 30 |
| 3 | 2 (Bicycle) | 5 |
| ... | ... |  |

How can I prevent each configuration from having two or more different configurations of each individual thing in the `thing_configurations` table?

| config_id | thing_config_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (20 Apples) |
| 1 | 2 (30 Apples) |
| ... | ... |

For example, in the above table, I have two conflicting configurations for Apples in configuration 1.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to enforce a uniqueness constraint for `config_id` and the `thing_id` referenced through the `thing_config_id`. Is that possible?

Comment: If you add a ConfigurationID column to ThingConfiguration, you can make the combination of ThingID and ConfigurationID unique. "ThingConfiguration" looks like a cross reference table, but you're referencing only the "thing" and not any "configuration".

Comment: @BrianStork But I don't want to tie a thing configuration to a specific configuration, which is why I'm not referencing a configuration within it. That is, the same thing configuration can be a part of multiple configurations (as defined in the `configurations` table). It's the purpose of the `config_thing_configurations` table to create that relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is possible, through the creation of an *indexed view* in combination with a unique index.

In this specific example, this is achieved by first creating a view that associates the configuration and thing identifiers:

```tsql
CREATE VIEW dbo.thing_config_view WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT
    thing_configurations.thing_id,
    config_thing_configurations.config_id
FROM dbo.config_thing_configurations
    INNER JOIN dbo.thing_configurations ON config_thing_configurations.thing_config_id = thing_configurations.id;
```

Next, we create a unique index on those fields from the view:

```tsql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [thing_config_view$unique_thing_configurations] ON dbo.thing_config_view(thing_id, config_id);
```

and it works exactly as required.

Answer (score 0):

This could be handled through Triggers. The trigger content would depend on what you want to occur when a query is called that would violate the condition. Something like this for insert (untested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_config_thing_configurations ON config_thing_configurations
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN thing_configurations tc ON tc.id = i.thing_config_id
        INNER JOIN things t ON t.id = tc.thing_id
        WHERE t.id IN (
            SELECT it.id
            FROM config_thing_configurations ictc
            INNER JOIN thing_configurations itc ON itc.id = ictc.thing_config_id
            INNER JOIN things it ON it.id = itc.thing_id
            WHERE 
                ictc.config_id = i.config_id
        )
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR ('Configuration already has a configuration for thing', 16, 1);  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        RETURN
    END

    INSERT INTO config_thing_configurations (config_id, thing_config_id) SELECT config_id, thing_config_id FROM inserted;

GO
```

You would need another for update or you could write a single to handle both cases.

Comment: That looks like it works, but I'd rather use constraints to ensure the integrity of the solution. It's also a little more verbose than the *indexed view* approach.

Comment: @FunProg In this case I would probably agree, but its good to have options. There are cases when a indexed view can not be created due to their unique creation constraints. More likely, there are cases where an index view may lead to performance issues due to SQL having to maintain both indexes on a highly volatile table leading to blocking issues.